# How do I access a variable that is an input to a method in another class?

Tags: python, tweepy

First time posting here, and new to python, so bear with me!

I am using the Tweepy library and am successfully using the Stream and StreamListener. I invoke the streamer, and return results, which are printed in the "on_data()" method in the StreamListener.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to access the query/hashtag variable that I used to invoke the Streamer, once the data is passed to the Listener.

Laying out my code below to help explain the question.

Here is create my TwitterStreamer object, and call the stream_tweets() method

```
twitter_streamer=TwitterStreamer()
twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(['canada'])
```

The stream_tweets method is part of the TwitterStream() class

```
    class TwitterStreamer():

    #Class for streaming and processing live tweets.


    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter_autenticator = TwitterAuthenticator()


    def stream_tweets(self, hash_tag_list):
        # This handles Twitter authentication and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
        listener = TwitterListener()
        auth = self.twitter_autenticator.authenticate_twitter_app()

        # This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:
        stream.filter(track=hash_tag_list)
```

Finally, I have another class StreamListener, which has a method from Tweepy "on_data()" which is invoked with the streamer returns data from the Twitter API

```
class TwitterListener(StreamListener):
#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
def on_data(self, data):
      all_data = json.loads(data)
      tweet = all_data['text']
      print(f"tweet: {tweet}")
      #PROBLEM print(f"{hashtag_tag_list}")
```

I would like to print the search variable that was initially passed to the stream_tweets() method ("canada") to the on_data method.  I am not sure how I access this variable, I imagine I am making it more complicated than needs to be!  Help very much appreciated.

Comment: Pass the variable when initializing the listener `listener = TwitterListener(hash_tag_list)`

Comment: Thanks Iain, I've passed the variable when initializing as you suggested, but I still cannot call variable hash_tag_list in the on_data() method in the TwitterListener class.